# Reverse the order of bounty questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bounties, active-bounties

Now the newest bounties are listed in the end of the list of bounties.

I propose to reverse the order, and show newest bounties in the beginning of the list of bounties.

This way newest bounties would be drawing attention as soon as they arrive. It would, in my opinion, decrease the average response time to a bounty.

Quicker answered bounties = better for bounty authors.

Answer (score 1):

On sites which use the new navigation bar, you can sort bounties per tag by "newest"

[image: Sort bounties]

You can also sort the general list of bounties by "newest" without a tag

[image: All bounties]

Comment: Good, but it should be the default order

Comment: That's also the "newest question", and not the "newest bounty".

Comment: Also worth noting that no sites actually use the new nav, it's an opt-in beta test available here and SO only that's seen no updates in a long time (unless something changed that I missed).